# Specific link in sentence

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

```
$input_lines = 'this photos {img='3512.jpg', alt='Title'} and {#img='3513.jpg', alt='Title2'} any image code here related to image must be replaced.';
echo preg_replace("/({\w+)/", "<img src='https://imgs.domain.com/images/$1' alt='$2'/>", $input_lines);
```

**Regex Code:**

`/({\w+)/`

**Image links:**

`{img='3512.jpg', alt='Title'}` and `{img='3513.jpg', alt='Title2'}` in sentence.

**Conversion:**

`this photos <img src='https://imgs.domain.com/images/3512.jpg' alt='Title'/>` and `<img src='https://imgs.domain.com/images/3513.jpg' alt='Title2'/> any image code here related to image must be replaced.`

I get the image links in the sentence but what's wrong with the Regex code?

Comment: You only have 1 capturing group in the pattern.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/vJHTsm

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I think you gave the downown but you responded at the same time. Thank you for your answer.If you want, we can write the answer. I want to mark your answer correctly

Comment: Please consider also upvoting the answer if it turned out helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `({\w+)` pattern only matches and captures into Group 1 a `{` and one or more word chars after the open brace. In your replacement pattern, there are `$1` and `$2` replacement backreferences that just can't "work" since you only have one capturing group.

You may use

```
$re = "/{#\w+='([^']*)'\s*,\s*\w+='([^']*)'}/";
$str = "this photos {#img='3512.jpg', alt='Title'} and {#img='3513.jpg', alt='Title2'} any image code here related to image must be replaced.";
$subst = "<img src='https://imgs.domain.com/images/\$1' alt='\$2'/>";
echo preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

See [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/KmaEZS), output

`this photos <img src='https://imgs.domain.com/images/3512.jpg' alt='Title'/> and <img src='https://imgs.domain.com/images/3513.jpg' alt='Title2'/> any image code here related to image must be replaced.`

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/G6tAVy/1).

**Details**

- `{#` - a substring `{#`
- `\w+` - 1 or more letters, digits or/and `_`
- `='` - a `='` literal substring
- `([^']*)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars other than `'`
- `'` - a `'`
- `\s*,\s*` - a comma enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
- `\w+=` - 1 or more letters, digits or/and `_` and a `='`
- `'` - a `'`
- `([^']*)` - Group 2:  any 0+ chars other than `'`
- `'}` - a `'}` string.